# i have image button and i wont to change the image when i click on it

Tags: android

I have two images, image 1 and image 2, and I have image_button which has image 1 as a button background. Now what I want to do is, if I press on this image_button, I want the image background to change to image 2, and if I take my finger off the image_button, I want the image 1 to be back again like it used to be.

How can I make this?

Comment: This should get you on the right track: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this programatically when a click occurs :

```
ImageView imageIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
imageIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.other_icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something called a selector.  In your drawable folder, create a xml file with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image2"/>
</selector>
```

Selectors are really useful for this kind of stuff, you should read the documentation

Basically, give this thing a name, like yourSelector.xml

You can use this the same as any other drawable, like @drawable/yourSelector or R.id.yourSelector (make sure not to write '.xml' though)